# Toggle Image on select in JSF extendedDataTable

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to get an image to swap back and forth based on if a row is selected in an extenedDataTable.  I am able to display the image in the non-active state but can't figure out how to toggle it.  Here is the table definition code:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable style="width: 800px; height: 150px;" 
rowClasses="Row0,Row1" value="#{myBean.exceptions}" var="exception"
selectionMode="single" id="Table" selection="#{myBean.exceptionSelection}">
<a4j:ajax event="selectionchange" listener="#{myBean.rowListener}" render=""/>
```

Here is the column whose image I want to toggle.  The idea is to change to an image called filledRadioButton in the same directory:

```
<rich:column id="selected_col" label="Selection">
<f:facet name="header">
<a4j:commandLink value="Selection" render="table"/>
</f:facet>
<h:graphicImage value="../resources/img/emptyRadioButton.jpg"/>
</rich:column>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dataTable's `ajaxKeys` attribute to specifically reference a row (or rows) for ajax update. So to effect this :

1. Bind the `ajaxKeys` attribute of your data table to a `Set<Integer>` in your backing bean. This set will hold unique `id` type values that will refer to specific entities in your datatable to be updated in an ajax response.
2. Add the `id` attribute of the `<h:graphicImage/>` you wish to update via ajax to the `render` list of your `<a4j:ajax/>`. Set the value of the image to a dynamic expression so you can switch it out in the backing bean

   ```
    <a4j:ajax event="selectionchange" listener="#{myBean.rowListener}" render="indicatorImg"/>        
    <h:graphicImage id="indicatorImg" value="#{myBean.desiredImagePath}"/>
   ```
3. Wire your ajax listener to add the id of the selected entity to the `ajaxKeys` Set and modify the `desiredImagePath` property as you see fit.

   ```
   public void rowListener(AjaxBehaviourEvent evt){
   //I assume you're already managing your selection properly
   //Change the value of the desiredImagePath here too.
    ajaxKeysSet.add(mySelection.getId()); //if you want to update multiple rows
           OR
    ajaxKeysSet = Collections.singleton(mySelection.getId()); //save a single id for ajax update
   }
   ```